# How to read lists of numbers from a file using string formats in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to get the list of numbers present in a file in a specific format. But I did not get any format (like %s %d) for list of numbers.

My file contains text as follows:

```
[1;2] [2] 5
[45;37] [9] 33
[3] [2;4] 1000
```

I tried the following

```
value split_input str fmt =  Scanf.sscanf str fmt (fun x y z -> (x,y,z));

value rec read_file chin acc fmt =
      try let line = input_line chin in
      let (a,b,c) = split_input line fmt in 
      let acc = List.append acc [(a,b,c)] in
            read_file chin acc fmt
      with 
      [ End_of_file -> do { close_in chin; acc}
      ];

value read_list = 
      let chin = open_in "filepath/filename" in
      read_file chin [] "%s %s %d";
```

The problem is with the format that is specified towards the end. I used the same code for getting data from some other file, where the data was in the format (string * string * int).

To reuse the same code I have to receive the above text in string and then split according to my requirement. My question is: is there a format like %s %d for a list of integers, so that I get the list directly from the file instead of writing another code to convert string to list.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in specifier for lists in `Scanf`. It is possible to use the `%r` specifier to delegate parsing to custom scanner, but `Scanf` is not really designed for parsing complex format:

```
let int_list b = Scanf.bscanf b "[%s@]" (fun s ->
  List.map int_of_string @@ String.split_on_char ';' s
)
```

Then with this `int_list` parser, we can write

```
let test = Scanf.sscanf "[1;2]@[3;4]" "%r@%r" int_list int_list (@)
```

and obtain

> val test : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]

as expected. But at the same time, it was easier to use `String.split_on_char` to do the splitting. In general parsing complicated format is better done with
a regexp library, a parser combinator library or a parser generator.

P.S: you should probably avoid the revised syntax, it has fallen into disuse.

Comment: The problem is I am new to Ocaml and I am using an already developed code which is written in the revised code. Will there be any issue if I add new code in the Ocaml syntax rather than the revised one?